# Tap on notification does not fire intent with deeplink when app is closed (not in recent)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am implementing push notification on Android with FirebaseMessagingService for an app that mainly lives in a webview.
The notifications arrives as expected when the app is in foreground, background and closed (wiped away).
Tapping a notification opens the deeplink provided in *data.payload.link* (after parsing the JSON in *data.payload*) when the app is in **forground** and **background** but **not when closed**.
In case the app is closed - the app gets started and shows up but the deeplink is **not** loaded like when the app is in foreground/background.

The payload I send to the Firebase API looks as follows:

```
          admin
              .messaging()
              .send({
                data: {
                  payload: JSON.stringify({
                    link: link || "",
                  }),
                },
                notification,
                android: {
                  notification: {
                    click_action: "OPEN_DEEPLINK_FROM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION",
                  },
                  priority: "normal",
                },
                token: recipient,
              })
```

The onMessageReceived() is implemented as follows:

```
   public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage == null) return;

        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String payload = (String) data.values().toArray()[0];
        String link = null;
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(payload);
            link = jObject.getString("link");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(PUSH_NOTIFICATION, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        notificationId = ++notificationId;
    }
```

The androidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorNotification" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.app.mobile.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_DEEPLINK_FROM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="app.myapp.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="app.myapp.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="app.myapp.ch" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="app.myapp.ch" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.myapp.app.mobile.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Opening deeplinks when an app is not running is handled in onPageFinished() of my WebViewClient instance (what works for openening deeplinks eg. from email when the app is not running):

```
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    Uri data = intent.getData();
                    if(intent.getData() != null){
                        openDeeplink(intent);
                    }
            }
```

I am wondering why this logic does not work in case of tapping a notification when the app was not running?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As firebese the docs describe here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive the data is delivered within the extras of the intent. This also applies for apps that are NOT running. I think the docs are not precise enough in this matter.
[image: Firebase docs]

The following fix did the trick in this case:

```
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    if(intent.getData() != null || intent.getExtras() != null){
                        openDeeplink(intent);
                    }
```